# how to copy source file into target file?

Tags: bash

Lets say I have file, named, blabla.txt which looks like this :

```
blabla.php <usb>blabla /bla/bla
blabla.js  <usb>blabla /bla/bla
```

I want to write script which will check if blabla.php, blabla.js exists,
one by one, and if string exist than will copy source file using path to target file using path and replace source instead of target file.

Source path would be:

```
 <usb>blabla
```

Target path would be:

```
/bla/bla
```

so I am first time in contact with bash scripts, and I would appreciate if you try to explain it on beginners level for me, I tried this until now ( also little bit is pseudo code ):

```
while read line; do
for filename in $line; do
if grep -Fxq "$filename" blabla.txt
cp $filename+1 $filename+2
done
done
```

I am sure that I made some big mistakes ( like trying to copy string into string but i dont know how to find path of actual file and copy )

Comment: It's hard to tell, if you name *everything* "blabla", what you want to copy to what.

Comment: I thought it is clear :D .php .js are only important as strings, so important is that they exist, if one exist than copy source file which has path usb etc, because this file is on usb, and replace it with another file bla/bla, that is path of target file. so it is kind of update mechanism, if filename exists in update.txt file, than replace file with changes with old one.

Comment: What is the significance of the `<usb>` part of the names?  Are the angle brackets `<>` actually a part of a file name?  Or is that a placeholder for `/mnt/usb-stick` or `/Volumes/USB-Stick` or something similar?  If the angle brackets are part of the name, you're treading on thin ice using them — they are not a part of the portable filename character set.

Comment: it should represent path to usb and file on it, but i just wrote it that way, path is also /.../....

Comment: OK.  For future reference, it's simpler all around if you just use a path like `/some/where` to represent an arbitrary path.  The fact that it is a USB stick is actually completely immaterial to the problems faced.  Do we have to worry about blanks and the like in file names?

Comment: yes it is just placeholder :)

Comment: filename would be something_something.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should read each column of the file into a different variable that represents its role.

```
while read -r filename sourcedir destdir
do
    if [[ -e "$sourcedir/$filename" ]]
    then 
        cp "$sourcedir/$filename" "$destdir"
    fi
done < inputfile
```

Comment: is while loop always reading only one line in bash scripts in general ?
did you write code for whole file, or only for one line of file ? if for whole code may you tell me where did you write that for each row new variable is made ?

Comment: The `read` command reads one line, but when you put it in a loop it repeats until it gets to the end of the file.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that the blanks in the file separate the important fields and are never part of a name, then you can do something along the lines of:

```
while read file source target junk
do
    if [ -n "$junk" ]
    then echo "Unexpected junk at end of line: $file $source $target $junk"
    elif [ -f "$source/$file" ]
    then
        [ -d "$target" ] || mkdir -p "$target" || exit 1
        cp "$source/$file" "$target/$file" || exit 1
    else
        echo "No such file: $source/$file" >&2
    fi
done < blabla.txt
```

The description of what you want to do isn't all that clear.

This code reads each line of `blabla.txt` into 4 variables, splitting on white space.  This is a fabulously useful feature of `read`.  Then the code checks that there are at most 3 fields on the line.  If there was extra information, it would be stored in `$junk`; the `-n` test checks whether `$junk` is non-empty and if so, the line is ignored.  If the source file exists (and is a file), then the code ensures that the target directory exists (creating it if it does not, and exiting if it fails to create it), and then copies the source file to the target directory (exiting if there is a problem).  If the source file doesn't exist, the problem is reported.

You can tweak this in multiple ways, depending on what you really want to do.  You can decide not to exit but to continue to the next line if there's a problem with directory creation, or the copy fails.  However, once on copy fails, it is likely that the rest will too.  For example:

```
    if [ -d "$target" ] || mkdir -p "$target"
    then cp "$source/$file" "$target/$file"
    fi
```

You can consider using [`read -r …`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/read.html); I don't, but I don't mind 'living dangerously' (but the aficionados around here prefer you to use it, so you get told you can use the `-r` and you can decide for yourself whether you will).